# Deleting a node that is in the middle of a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

I am trying to delete a node in the middle of two other nodes in a singly linked list.

```
public void deleteAfter(Node del){
        del.next=del.next.next; 
    }
```

where it deletes the the node that is after the specified node,del.
I get a null pointer exception .I think the problem is after deletion the link with other nodes is broken.How can I mend it .Here's my full code :

```
public class Node{
    public Object item;
    public Node next;
    public Node(){
        item=null;
        next=null;
    }
    public Node(Object x){
        item=x;     
        next=null;
    }

    public void insertAfter(Node after,Object x){
        Node newNode=new Node(x);
        newNode.next=after.next;
        after.next=newNode;
    }
    public void deleteAfter(Node del){//Deletes the node that is after the specified node
        del.next=del.next.next; 
    }
    public static void main (String args[]){
    Node front=new Node(),p=new Node(),q=new Node();
    p.item="green";
    q.item="red";
    p.next=q;
    front=p;
    front.deleteAfter(p);
    front.insertAfter(p,"black");

    front.insertAfter(q,"blue");
    front.insertAfter(q.next,"orange");
    front.deleteAfter(q);
    System.out.println(front.item);
    System.out.println(front.next.item);
    System.out.println(front.next.next.item);
    System.out.println(front.next.next.next.item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your delete code doesn't handle the case where the input is itself the last node.

Comment: This is when the node to be deleted is in the middle of two other nodes

Answer (score 1):

First your list should remember last element or head.

```
public class YourList{
   Node heaed;
   public YourList(){
      head = null;
  }
  public void insert(Node node){
     if(last == null){
        head = node;
     } 
  }
  public void deleteAfter(Node del){
        if(del.next == head)){
            head = del;
         }
        if(del.next == null){
           //do nothing because there is nothing to delete
        }
        else{
        del.next=del.next.next; 
        }
   }

 }
```

Comment: Why do I have to remember last or head element.If a middle node is removed then why isn't `del.next=del.next.next; `enough

Comment: Because when you don't have any handle for your list data. So simply it is pointless to add any element because you can not retreive it :) Please paste your `List` structure.

Comment: List structure is defined in the main method

Answer (score 0):

At:

```
    p.next=q;
    front=p;
    front.deleteAfter(p);
    front.insertAfter(p,"black");
```

You have created a two node linked list starting at `p`, and pointed `front` to it, then you shrank it down to a one node linked list, and bumped it back to two, consisting of { "green", "black" }. `q` is a singleton list node which you later manipulate.

When you print starting from `front`, since it only has two nodes, trying to obtain the `item` of the third node, which doesn't exist, causes your exception.

Your question started out by asking if there was something wrong with your `deleteAfter()`, and there is in that it won't correctly handle any correct list of nodes, only a list that actually has something after it. Passing in an empty list or a list with only one node in it will result in an exception.

Comment: though I initially create only two nodes p,q when I call on the methods inserFront() I am creating new nodes right? So how can `"When you print starting from front, since it only has two nodes, trying to obtain the item of the third node, which doesn't exist, causes your exception."` happen?Because there are 3 nodes "red","green",q

Comment: `front.deleteAfter(p)` reduces the list by one so that it only has one node. Then `front.insertAfter(p,"black")` increases it from one back to two.

Answer (score 0):

You can first find the middle node using two pointer approach and then delete the node.

```
public Node findMiddleNode(Node node){
    Node runner = node;
    while(node!=null){
        node = node.next;
        if(node != null){
            node = node.next;
            runner = runner.next;
        }
    }
    return runner;
}

public static boolean deleteNode(Node node){
    if(node==null || node.next==null) return false;
    Node next = node.next;
    node.data = next.data;
    node.next = next.next;

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution which first calculates the size of the list and deletes the n/2 element **without using two pointers**.

For example, if given linked list is 1->2->3->4->5 then linked list should be modified to 1->2->4->5. If there are even nodes, then there would be two middle nodes, the second middle element gets deleted. For example, if given linked list is 1->2->3->4->5->6 then it should be modified to 1->2->3->5->6.

```
    public void deleteMiddle() {

    if (head == null) {
        System.out.println("List is emplty");
        return;
    } else if (head.next == null) {
        head = null;
        return;
    } else {
        int count = 0;
        int nodeDeleteIndex = 0;
        Node node = this.head;
        Node temp = this.head;

        // To calculate the list size
        while (node != null) {
            count++;
            node = node.next;
        }
        // getting the n/2 index of the node which needs to be deleted
        nodeDeleteIndex = (count / 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeDeleteIndex - 1; i++) {
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        temp.next = temp.next.next;
    }
}
```